# Can a pug (either puppy or adult) be left alone for 7 hours?

Tags: dogs

I would like to buy a pug puppy in September, but I work for seven hours across the street. I could check on my pug every 5 hours and would provide with water, pee pads, crate and toys. But I don’t know if this would be OK?

Please help me and offer your insight.

Comment: Put your best foot forward. When you get the dog, on the first few nights, the dog will whine/cry/making noises that draws you to them for the entire night. Do not goto them until one night they will stop this altogether. This will make your life much easier for the rest of the dog's life. I did this with my GSD, while it cried for 2 nights in a row and 3rd night, no noise at all. I left the dog for 11-12 hours a day due to work and commute. As long as you trained for the dog to pee on pads, no issues

Comment: You can also get a dog pen attached to a crate, this way your dog should never pee in the crate. Put the pee pad in the pen of course

Answer (score 2):

Generally to leave any dog alone takes training them for a while to be able to be alone and be ok with it.

Start small with crate training, putting them in a crate with a treat or toy and work up from here. Progress to slightly longer absences and leave it to roam where you allow it to. Build it up say 30mins/1 hour at a time. Reward the dog every time you come back too, this reinforces that you will come back.

This builds the dogs confidence to be content alone and being able to cope. It will eventually build a routine and be ok with it.

If you don’t, bored dogs, dogs with separation anxiety can become destructive without putting this groundwork in.

Answer (score 1):

That would be OK as long as you each room is safe for the dog.

I would suggest securing any loose or dangling wires; and if you have house plants, keep them out of reach (some plants are toxic for dogs).

Comment: Thank you so much I will make sure my house is dog friendly before I buy a dog